# onFormSubmit trigger removes when update G-Suite add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms, google-apps-script-addon

I want create a standalone add-on for google form which should handle form-submit event with creation a new text file in google drive with content of the form response. And then distrubute this add-on for other users.
**My goal is user can install the add-on on google form and it just should work, without additional setup from add-on menu.**

While testing I figured out that there are [Simple](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) and [Installable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) triggers are available. (`onFormSubmit` is an installable trigger)
Installable triggers clear each time when add-on is updated on G-Suite Marketplace. Therefore it removes my `onFormSubmit` trigger, and because of that *the installed add-on stops working after update*.

`onFormSubmit` trigger is added inside `onInstall` Simple trigger this way:

```
function onInstall() {
    var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
    var trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger('respondToFormSubmit')
       .forForm(form)
       .onFormSubmit()
       .create();
}
```

I thought to bypass this issue by handling `onFormSubmit` inside Simple trigger `onEdit` of the linked spreadsheet. Actually it could check a spreadsheet for new rows and then create a new file. But Simple triggers are without autorization to private services (like google drive), so *it's not possible to create a file on google drive inside a simple trigger*.

Is there way to keep `onFormSubmit` trigger after publish a new version of add-on, without its manual re-install? 
Well, these all reasonable, but then why `onInstall` event is not raised again? Or may be is there an event `onUpdate` to handle add-on update?

**UPDATE**

[Here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) I read:

> Add-on triggers will stop firing in any of the following situations:
>
> - If the add-on is uninstalled by the user
> - If the add-on is disabled in a document (if it is re-enabled, the trigger will become operational again)
> - **If the developer unpublishes the add-on or submits a broken version to the add-on store**

I just set next version number in the publish form, click "Update web store draft", and confirm update in new window. Am I doing everything right?

[image]

The trigger stops firing even without code modifications, just with new version of add-on. And there are no any log errors in stackdriver console. Could it be a bug?

Comment: Even with an addon, I believe the user still needs to enable the trigger. There are security concerns when you're silently enabling a trigger to do something without the user being made aware.

Comment: Take a look to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/quickstart/forms-add-on. It's handles onformsubmit trigger reauthorization